# Proper Zariski closed sets have measure zero- not necessarily in $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$

Tags: measure-theory, algebraic-geometry

In $\mathbb{R}^n$ one can prove that a proper Zariski closed set has measure zero (with respect to Lebesgue measure).

Can this statement be generalized to varieties in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

In particular, can we induce the Lebesgue measure onto a proper Zariski closed set :$V$ so that any proper Zariski closed set $U\subsetneq V$ will have measure zero.

Comment: Almost everywhere, a variety looks like a manifold and a proper closed subset like a submanifold of lower dimension. Hence by the measure of the main varieties dimension induced from Lebesgue measure of the surrounding space, th esubvariety is a zero set.

Comment: That's the same exact answer I gave here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/138057/do-proper-zariski-closed-sets-of-algebraic-sets-have-measure-zero#comment356137_138057

Comment: Any complement of a closed subset is an open set so that its closure is the whole space. This shows that the measure is 0.

Comment: Perhaps I should have made the problem with the problem clearer. Once one can show that under some induced measure sets with strictly lower dimension have measure zero then the result would follow. However one still has to show that.